# neo4j, py2neo: How to search a node using its properties

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

I am using py2neo on Neo4j for my self study project. I have two codes, one for creating nodes and another one for creating relations between the nodes. I have successfully created nodes using py2neo with following attributes
EmpNum
Name
Role

I need to search for two nodes based on EmpNum store it into two variables and then create a relation between them. I searched for the same and got some links as follows
[Searching for node in py2neo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681305/searching-for-node-in-py2neo) 
and
[Working with indexes in neo4j and py2neo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903909/working-with-indexes-in-neo4j-and-py2neo?rq=1)

but none of them are what i am expecting. Please help me as i am not able to proceed

Comment: So, what is (not) happening? Got the code somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a parameterised Cypher query for this. Something like the following takes two parameters - `num_a` and `num_b` and creates a relationship between them. You could also change `CREATE` to `CREATE UNIQUE` to make sure you don't get duplicates.

```
MATCH (a {EmpNum:{num_a}}), (b {EmpNum:{num_b}})
CREATE (a)-[ab:RELATES_TO]->(b)
RETURN ab
```

To execute Cypher in py2neo, use the [CypherQuery](http://nigelsmall.com/py2neo/1.6/cypher/#py2neo.neo4j.CypherQuery) object.